# Erro com SessionExpirationScheduler no widfly

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-modules

Quando alterei o `jboss` all para usar o shared session, a minha aplicação depois de um tempo começa a da esse erro abaixo, alguém sabe como resolver?

> ```
> 12:08:40,332 WARN  [org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction]
> (SessionExpirationScheduler - 1) ISPN000112: exception while
> committing: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.getLocalTransactionAndValidateImpl(TransactionXaAdapter.java:239)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.getLocalTransactionAndValidate(TransactionXaAdapter.java:232)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.commit(TransactionXaAdapter.java:101)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.finishResource(DummyTransaction.java:367)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commitResources(DummyTransaction.java:413)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.runCommit(DummyTransaction.java:303)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commit(DummyTransaction.java:104)
>   at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyBaseTransactionManager.commit(DummyBaseTransactionManager.java:73)
>   at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.ActiveTransactionBatch.close(ActiveTransactionBatch.java:48)
>   at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.SessionExpirationScheduler$ExpirationTask.run(SessionExpirationScheduler.java:149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
> ```